# Why this Python parallel loop is taking longer time than sequential loop?

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I have this code that I tried to make parallel based on a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45649163/python-how-to-parallelize-loops). Here is the code using 2 processes.

```
import  multiprocessing
import timeit

start_time = timeit.default_timer()

d1 = dict( (i,tuple([i*0.1,i*0.2,i*0.3])) for i in range(500000) )
d2={}

def fun1(gn):
    x,y,z = d1[gn]
    d2.update({gn:((x+y+z)/3)})

#
if __name__ == '__main__':
    gen1 = [x for x in d1.keys()]
    #fun1(gen1)
    p= multiprocessing.Pool(2)
    p.map(fun1,gen1)
    print('Script finished')
    stop_time = timeit.default_timer()
    print(stop_time - start_time)
```

Output is:

```
Script finished
1.8478448875989333
```

If I change the program to sequential,

```
fun1(gen1)
#p= multiprocessing.Pool(2)
#p.map(fun1,gen1)
```

output is:

```
Script finished
0.8345944193950299
```

So parallel loop is taking more time that sequential loop, more than double. (My computer has 2 cores, running on Windows.) I tried to find similar questions on the topic, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32020662/python-multiprocessing-takes-more-time) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373131/why-is-there-no-speed-up-when-using-pythons-multiprocessing-for-embarassingly-pa?rq=1) but could not figure out the reason. How can I get performance improvement using multiprocessing module in this example?

Comment: If all you're doing is adding numbers, that's probably not an expensive enough operation to overcome the overhead of creating the pool.

Comment: `fun1(gen1)` is not equal to the multiprocessing code.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `p.map(fun1,gen1)` you send `gen1` over to the other process. This includes serializing the list which is 500000 elements big.

Comparing serialization to the small computation, it takes much longer.

You can measure or `profile` where the time is spent.